# inner class: not public and cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android, package, inner-classes, public

I have a GpsService in a package (packageShared) and I need to access it from another package (packageClient). I am getting "getService() is not public in 'packageShared.GpsService.Localbinder'. Can not be accessed from outside package." on the following line mService = (GpsService) binder.getService(); at the Android Studio.

I have another class inside the packageShared the works great using the same code.

Here the code on the packageClient:

```
    // Monitors the state of the connection to the service.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        GpsService.LocalBinder binder = (GpsService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = (GpsService) binder.getService();
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Here is the code on the packageShared:

```
public class GpsService extends Service {


    public GpsService() {
    }

    other methods here...

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Since this service runs in the same process as its
     * clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        GpsService getService() {
            return GpsService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your `getService()` method is package-visible. You need to make it `public` in order to access it from other packages:

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public GpsService getService() {   //<-- The public keyword is added
        return GpsService.this;
    }
}
```